# Website content is pushed left when viewed in Android browsers

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, frontend, mobile-webkit

This website's content is bunched to the left when viewed on android browsers, as demonstrated in the two screenshots below. I feel like I've come across other websites with this issue when using my mobile browser, so I'm thinking it isn't an uncommon issue.

The site isn't responsive (yet) and there are no media queries. I am not using the viewport meta tag, to prevent initial zoom-in on a non-responsive site (as detailed [here](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho)).

The issue isn't happening on:

- iOS Simulator, Safari Browser
- Opera Mobile Emulator (emulating opera running android devices like Kindle Fire and HTC phones)
- Android Samsung Smartphone, Firefox and Opera browsers

The issue is happening on:

- Android SDK, (emulating an android browser on a Nexus S)
- A Samsung Galaxy S2 (pictured below), in Chrome, Dolphin, & Default browser

Here are the details for the device in the screenshot:

```
device_model = samsung SGH-T989
device_res = 480x800
orientation = portrait
os_name = Android
os_version = 4.0.4
pixel_density = 240 dpi
url = http://bryanbraun.com/
```

**Mobile Version**

[image: Mobile Version -- Text is constrained and pushed to the left.]

**Desktop Version**

[image: Desktop Version -- Text is aligned properly]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a background-color on the tags which contain the text. This way, android will (hopefully) consider these some kind of blocks and (probably) will render them fine.